# C# enumerable property like .Any that accounts for nulls

Tags: c#, generics, iterator, null

**Brief Description**:

A generic extension method that performs the same function as `IEnumerable.Any()`, but does not throw an error when passed a parameter with a `null` value.

**Explanation**:

Often times I will come across code that performs two steps on a nullable collection to make sure it contains elements. The first step checks to make sure the collection is not `null`, then the second step looks to see that there are greater than zero elements.

For example, to make sure a `List<T>` meets these qualifications before working through each element, code might look like this:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();

if (
    intList != null &&
    intList.Any()
    )
{
    foreach (int intElement in intList)
    {
        // logic here
. . .
```

To reiterate, just using `.Any()` above would be insufficient for the situation where `intList` hasn't yet been initialized.

Because this is a common occurrence in the code I maintain, I've come up with a generic extension method that performs the same function as the above, in one method:

```
static class CLR
{
    public static bool Populated<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        return source != null && source.Any();
    }
. . .
```

... which renders the first block a little simpler:

```
if (intList.Populated())
{
    foreach (int intElement in intList)
    {
        // logic here
. . .
```

Are there suggestions for why this should not be implemented, or why it should be implemented in a different form?

Comment: In C# 6 you can just do `collection?.Any()` ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t nice tip! unfortuantely .NET 3.5.

Comment: Any `IEnumerable` reference that is `null` means bad code. Best practice since .net 1.1 has been to yield/return an empty collection when there are no items, not a null reference. This extension method is working around a severe problem with the code, rather than solving it. I'd much rather hunt down instances of code returning `null` and change them to return an empty enumerable instead; that way you fix what's wrong instead of introducing a way to make the wrong seem right... just my two cents ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug wise words... unfortunatelly you can't count on it when working with 3rd party libs that hasn't been reviewed here ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I think I understand what you're saying, but could you point me towards something that reviews the concept of why `IEnumerable` null references are bad?

Comment: [Null is not Empty](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/14/null-is-not-empty/) by Eric Lippert. And [Framework Design Guidelines 2nd edition, p.256](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321545613), and [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1969993/1188513) ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug thank you - and, i think you're comment qualifies as an answer, since it's caused me to think about why i should not implement - exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Fair enough, I added an answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C# 6 you could simply do `collection?.Any()`

but in older versions I use a more generic solution for the same thing because there a more situations where something could be null.

This is my helper:

```
static class Helpers
{
    public static TResult If<TArg, TResult>
    (
        this TArg arg,
        Func<TArg, bool> predicate,
        Func<TArg, TResult> trueFunc,
        Func<TArg, TResult> falseFunc = null
    )
    {
        return 
            predicate(arg) 
            ? trueFunc(arg) 
            : (falseFunc == null ? default(TResult) : falseFunc(arg));
    }

    public static TResult IfNotNull<TArg, TResult>(
        this TArg arg, 
        Func<TArg, TResult> trueFunc
    ) where TArg : class
    {
        return arg.If(x => x != null, x => trueFunc(x));
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
var foo = (List<int>)null;
var hasAny1 = foo.If(x => x != null, x => x.Any()); // false
var hasAny2 = foo.IfNotNull(x => x.Any()); // false
```

Answer (score 3):

My point of view is different depending on whether the the code that's returning `null` enumerables is a 3rd-party API or your own code.

---

#### 3rd-Party

If the code that's returning `null` enumerables is a 3rd-party API, then I only have a few minor points to mention:

- `CLR` is a very bad and misleading name for a class. In the .NET world CLR stands for *Common Language Runtime*, the part that's responsible for JIT-compiling CIL code (which all .net languages compile to), a bit like the JVM does for byte code / compiled Java.
- I would have named `Populated` with a little `Is` prefix to read like `IsPopulated`, because I like Boolean functions/properties to read that way. But that's personal preference.

The implementation itself is nice & clean, nothing to say about it (other than the C# 6 trick in [t3chb0t's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/138566/23788)); I like that you named the `this` parameter `source`, it lines up with other framework-provided `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods, e.g. LINQ. `TSource` seems a bit verbose when `T` would have been sufficient, but I like descriptive generic type parameters so I'd leave it as is.

In the sample code, you have this:

> ```
> if (
>     intList != null &&
>     intList.Any()
>     )
> ```

That looks terrible; an `if` condition should fit one single line:

```
if (intList != null && intList.Any())
```

Very long conditions that actually need to be multiple lines, should be extracted out of the `if` statement and into their own function with a meaningful name that captures the meaning of all these conditions:

```
if (IsValid(intList))
```

You get the idea; that's usually more commonly seen with LINQ queries and predicates though, but the concept is the same: if it's too much clutter to be readable, move it elsewhere and abstract it behind a meaningful identifier.

---

#### Your own

On the other hand, if the code that's returning `null` enumerables is under your control, there's a bigger issue.

Per [Framework Design Guidelines 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321545613), p.256:

> **DO NOT** return null values from collection properties or from methods returning collections. Return an empty collection or an empty array instead.

See [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969993/1188513) for more information about whether it's *better to return null or an empty collection*.

Instead of introducing an extension method to work around a serious design issue in your code base, you should be hunting down instances of `IEnumerable<T>`-returning methods and properties in that code base, and *fixing* them so that they return an empty enumerable instead of a `null` value:

```
return Enumerable.Empty<Foo>();
```

Then all you need to do is get rid of redundant but inoffensive null-checks everywhere in the code base, and new code wouldn't need any such null-checks.